# You might find me in a costly lawsuit. What am I?

Tags: riddle

## **About Me**

Pros:

> 1. I always let my friends go first.
> 2. To some of my groups of friends, I mean every.
> 3. No matter who I am around, I always have an effect on them.
> 4. I am strong-willed; none of my friends can change me.
> 5. I have a magnetic personality, so I am always near friends.

Cons:

> 1. I'm short.
> 2. I do not like to be alone- I am clingy.
> 3. I never accept some groups of my friends for who they are, and instead, I try to change them, and always succeed.
> 4. I'm bossy- usually the one telling my friends when, where, how, why, and under what circumstances things are going to happen.
> 5. I have 2 personalities- one is almost a teenager, and the other is in his mid twenties

Hint:

> The title is a hint. Don't overlook it.

Comment: Figured I'd have a look at the anagrams for 'a costly lawsuit'. Turns out there's plenty of them. Perhaps a starting point? http://wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=a+costly+lawsuit&t=1000&a=n

Comment: I can easily relate 'cons' to my girlfriend... :P

Comment: @Tim Couwelier  Good idea, but there are no anagrams in this puzzle

Comment: @Deepak Your girlfriend is in HIS mid twenties? :-o

Comment: @randal'thor You got me.. :p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The letters ly

I always let my friends go first.

> ly appears at the ends of words to make them adverbs, usually

To some of my groups of friends, I mean everything.

> Thinking about the ly in the context of the word poly, meaning every

No matter who I am around, I always have an effect on them.

> ly turns some words into adverbs when added to the end

I am strong-willed; none of my friends can change me.

> adding suffixes to ly doesnt change it

I have a magnetic personality, so I am always near friends.

> ly on it's own doesn't mean anything

I'm short.

> only two letters

I do not like to be alone- I am clingy.

> again, only has meaning when added onto an existing word

I never accept some groups of my friends for who they are, and instead, I try to change them, and always succeed.

> adding ly changes adjectives into adverbs

I'm bossy- usually the one telling my friends when, where, how, why, and under what circumstances things are going to happen.

> adverbs describe how something is happening

I have 2 personalities- one is almost a teenager, and the other is in his mid twenties

> l is the 12th letter of the alphabet, y is the 25th

also

> camerons answer was really the springboard for my understanding of this

Comment: This *has* to be correct! It makes so much sense.

Comment: Well done, Kik! A few things: "means every" in friend groups like hour, day, month, year, turning them to yearly, monthly, daily, etc.   L is the 12th letter of the alphabet.  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-ly     and     http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/adverbs.htm

Comment: @JLee haha yeh, guess I need to learn to count!

Comment: Also, technically the answer was intended to be "the suffix -ly", which explains the apparent inconsistency you brought up with "lycanthrope"

Comment: Nice**ly** done ;-)

Comment: Well done. Though I agree with Jlee on the "every" point (as *poly* means *many*)

Answer (score 10):

Is it

> the letter Y?

The two personalities:

> the i sound ('i' is 9th letter of alphabet, almost a teen) and the y sound ('y' is 25th letter, mid twenties).

It's never by itself (in English).

> Modifies words (like 'ever' into 'every')
>
>  Other letters don't modify its pronunciation.

It's in the question.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to suggest

> An asterisk (*).
> Lawyers are fond of addenda and footnotes and the like, so a printed lawsuit is likely to contain a lot of them.

1. I always let my friends go first.

   > An asterisk is almost always found after a word.
2. To some of my groups of friends, I mean every*thing*.

   > In a computer/programming context, the asterisk is often used as a wildcard to mean "everything".
3. No matter who I am around, I always have an effect on them.

   > Whenever there's and asterisk after a word, it means there something more to say about that word (an "effect").
4. I am strong-willed; none of my friends can change me.

   > The asterisk affects the word it's on, but the word doesn't affect the asterisk.
5. I have a magnetic personality, so I am always near friends.

   > An asterisk is rarely found on its own, but always at the end of a word.

Cons:

1. I'm short.

   > The height of the asterisk is not very much.
2. I do not like to be alone- I am clingy.

   > Like #5 above -- it's always on a word.
3. I never accept some groups of my friends for who they are, and instead, I try to change them, and always succeed.

   > The purpose of the asterisk is to supply a "modifier" for the word(s).  It changes the meaning in some way.
4. I'm bossy- usually the one telling my friends when, where, how, why, and under what circumstances things are going to happen.

   > Asterisks are often used for the "fine print" in deals, contests, etc., where they detail all the specifics.
5. I have 2 personalities- one is almost a teenager, and the other is in his mid twenties.

   > This refers to the locations of the two * keys on a typical keyboard.

Comment: +1 Based on type of puzzle, I think this is the closest answer so far. Great explanations though. I will give a hint sometime today if no one gets it.

Comment: I don't follow on CON #5. My asterisks are on the 8 key and by itself on the number pad. How that does become almost a teenager and mid twenties?

Comment: @EngineerToast, I was thinking if you counted the number of keys across, depending on the keyboard, the "8" key would be #9 or #10, which is "almost a teenager", and the "*" key (on the number pad) would be somewhere around #20 (keyboards vary).

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> Wedding rings

**Pros**


*I always let my friends go first.*

> Since the wedding ring is in the beginning of your finger, everything you do or touch, you do it before the ring touches it (figuratively speaking).

*To some of my groups of friends, I mean everything.*

> That's true. For some people, the marriage is everything.

*No matter who I am around, I always have an effect on them.*

> When you wear a ring, this always means something for you.

*I am strong-willed; none of my friends can change me.*

> The gold is very very hard metal.

*I have a magnetic personality, so I am always near friends.*

> You wear it all the time.

**Cons**


*I'm short.*

> I'm small.

*I do not like to be alone- I am clingy.*

> Wedding rings are meant to be worn.

*I never accept some groups of my friends for who they are, and instead, I try to change them, and always succeed.*

> I think this has something to do with adultery?!

*I'm bossy- usually the one telling my friends when, where, how, why, and under what circumstances things are going to happen.*

> This I couldn't figure out.

*I have 2 personalities- one is almost a teenager, and the other is in his mid twenties*

> Female and male wedding rings. They have different size.

Comment: Actually gold is a very soft metal.

Comment: +1 Good thoughts, but not the right track. I might need to add another hint soon.

Answer (score 2):

Is it...

> decimal point?

You might find me in a costly lawsuit. What am I?

> Costly lawsuits have big numbers maybe with decimal points or thousand separators

I always let my friends go first.

> Other numbers are followed by decimal point

To some of my groups of friends, I mean everything.

> If the friends are fraction they can't be showed without decimal point

No matter who I am around, I always have an effect on them.

> Put decimal point anywhere in a number and you will change it

I am strong-willed; none of my friends can change me.

> No matter what is the math operation, you will not change it, just move it.

I have a magnetic personality, so I am always near friends.

> Decimal number is always side by side with numbers

I'm short.

> It is short

I do not like to be alone- I am clingy.

> It needs other numbers to be 'visible'

I never accept some groups of my friends for who they are, and instead, I try to change them, and always succeed.

> You change numbers if you use decimal point

I'm bossy- usually the one telling my friends when, where, how, why, and under what circumstances things are going to happen.

> You decide how big the number is starting from decimal point

I have 2 personalities- one is almost a teenager, and the other is in his mid twenties

> No idea - my previous idea was Zero

Answer (score 2):

Based on Hint #1, I came up with the following answer:

> TO/TOO/TWO. A *phonetic* answer, a string of phonemes rather than a string of letters - interesting idea for a riddle!

*1.I always let my friends go first.*

> One goes first, before *two*.

*2.To some of my groups of friends, I mean every[thing].*

> If you're French, the string of phonemes that is the answer comes out as *tout*, meaning "every".

*3.No matter who I am around, I always have an effect on them.*

> The word *too* always has an effect on the other words around it: it emphasises them, in a way.

*4.I am strong-willed; none of my friends can change me.*

> Could again refer to the word *too*.

*5.I have a magnetic personality, so I am always near friends.*

> None of these words normally appear on their own, but rather surrounded by other words.

*1.I'm short.*

> All of these words (especially *to*) are short.

*2.I do not like to be alone- I am clingy.*

> *Two* things are not alone. Alternatively this could have the same interpretation as Pro #5.

*3.I never accept some groups of my friends for who they are, and instead, I try to change them, and always succeed.*

> This is *too* again. It changes the words it describes.

*4.I'm bossy- usually the one telling my friends when, where, how, why, and under what circumstances things are going to happen.*

> This could be *to*, always coming before a verb in the infinitive form.

*5.I have 2 personalities- one is almost a teenager, and the other is in his mid twenties*

> The two letters of "to" are 20 and 15: 15 is a teenager, and 20 is in his twenties. Not mid-twenties though, so maybe there's another explanation for this line!

Comment: +1 Excellent explanations, but that's not it. I will add a 2nd hint soon.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> time?
>  Time is short. It has 2 personalities: 12 or 24 hours.

About friends

> Friends are clocks. They can't change time, but they're affected by it. Some clocks only show time, so it's everything to them.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try again:

> A hyphen

Pros:

1. I always let my friends go first.

   > A hyphen is found in the middle of a word, so there are letters before it.
2. To some of my groups of friends, I mean everything.

   > When specifying a group, like "A-Z", the hyphen indicates everything in between.
3. No matter who I am around, I always have an effect on them.

   > The hyphen modifies words, and changes their meaning.
4. I am strong-willed; none of my friends can change me.

   > It means the same thing, regardless of what is around it.
5. I have a magnetic personality, so I am always near friends.

   > The hyphen shows up in the middle of words

Cons:

1. I'm short.

   > It's a short dash.
2. I do not like to be alone- I am clingy.

   > Again, it's always within a word.
3. I never accept some groups of my friends for who they are, and instead, I try to change them, and always succeed.

   > Adding a hyphen tacks something else on, which changes the meaning of a word.
4. I'm bossy- usually the one telling my friends when, where, how, why, and under what circumstances things are going to happen.

   > A hyphen is sometimes used (incorrectly) for injection into a sentence - like this - instead of the "em-dash".  That's often used when giving instructions or telling people what to do.
5. I have 2 personalities- one is almost a teenager, and the other is in his mid twenties.

   > The hyphen is key #12 across my keyboard, and the similar "minus sign" on the numeric keypad is #22.

Comment: +1 No, but great explanations again. It is not a punctuation mark (such as a hyphen or asterisk). I added a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of [Cameron's "painfully close" answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/11846/5373), but slightly different and with more clues explained:

> the letter I.

Obviously this makes the question something of a "lynch-mob" riddle, what with all the referring to the answer as "I". Here are (at least some of) the clues explained one by one.

Title:

> I appears in the words "a costly lawsu**i**t".

*I always let my friends go first.*

> Some letters come before I in the alphabet.

*To some of my groups of friends, I mean everything.*

> Egomaniacs?

*No matter who I am around, I always have an effect on them.*

> ???

*I am strong-willed; none of my friends can change me.*

> The letter I doesn't change no matter how many other letters it's surrounded by.

*I have a magnetic personality, so I am always near friends.*

> ???

*I'm short.*

> Lower-case i looks like a short person with a head.

*I do not like to be alone- I am clingy.*

> The letter I often appears in the middle of a word along with other letters.

*I never accept some groups of my friends for who they are, and instead, I try to change them, and always succeed.*

> Maybe as Cameron suggested, referring to words that change with the insertion of an extra letter I - e.g. "her"->"heir".

*I'm bossy- usually the one telling my friends when, where, how, why, and under what circumstances things are going to happen.*

> ???

*I have 2 personalities- one is almost a teenager, and the other is in his mid twenties*

> As Cameron said, this refers to I and Y. He just picked the wrong one of the two as his answer!