# a riddle i places b4 u

Tags: riddle

> $do$ $u$ $know$ $y$ $i$ $exists?$
>   $bcos$ $i$ $is$ $that$ $that$ $does$ $not$ $exist$
>   $in$ $plane$ $terms$ $i$ $wanders:$ $y$ $is$ $i$
>
> $sum1$ $and$ $i$ $in$ $a$ $relationship:$ $its$ $complicated$
>   $at$ $times$ $i$ $is$ $in$ $heaven$ $with$ $an$ $angle$
>   $\&$ $other$ $times$ $on$ $the$ $ground$ $-$ $bless$ $i,$ $4$ $i$ $has$ $sin$

Comment: even though I know that this riddle is supposed to be written in this way, but I just want to say it : There are too many typos in this puzzle. Please consider editing it so that other users can read it. Also consider taking a [tour] of this site again. :D

Comment: @manshu: What typos?

Comment: for example: angle, some1, y, bcos etc. (But I know that they are intended)

Comment: "bcos" is an abbreviation, not a typo.  What's wrong with "angle"? - my spell checker seems to be satisfied with it...

Comment: angle is between two lines. While Angel is in heavens.

Comment: When the gates of heaven are opening, isn't there an angle between them?

Comment: [This](http://cdn-4.analyzemath.com/Geometry/angle_1.gif) is angle and [this](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/p__/images/2/2e/7639650_orig.jpg) is angel. Choose for yourself.

Comment: @JonathanAllan: Seems that adding the right tag to many of my puzzles would end up being a spoiler.  ;)

Comment: Um, but it's blatant

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'll take a go at it and say it's

> [The Imaginary Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit).

my reasoning:

do u know y i exists? 
bcos i is that that does not exist

> i is something that does not exist

in plane terms i wanders : y is i

> This seems like something related to plotting on a coordinate plane: In the complex plane, the y-axis is the imaginary axis representing i -- the imaginary unit.

sum1 and i in a relationship: it's complicated

> Now it definitely is a mathematical quantity. and when we add 1 + i we get something "complex": a complex number! so we can confirm that i is the imaginary unit.

at times i is in heaven with an angle

> i can be in the exponent of e with an angle, say $ \theta $ to get $ e^{i\theta} $

&& other times on the ground −− bless i, 4 i has sin

> i appears on the ground when we use Euler's formula to rewrite $ e^{i\theta} $ as $ cos\theta + isin\theta $

Comment: Correct!  The topic was the symbol/unit in general (which exists for the purpose of denoting things that don't exist), and not specifically the formula.