# Why, a math riddle for you!

Tags: riddle, mathematics

> I am not real, 
> but I am part of a complicated thing. 
> Two is negative?

> What am I?

Comment: [Similar previous riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/31630/5373). Also [a deleted one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/12175/5373).

Comment: I made this one up myself.

Comment: I know, just linking some places where people had pretty much the same idea for a riddle before.

Comment: To perhaps explain the downvotes: this is incredibly simple, and also very short. I think probably everyone who looks at this with any knowledge of maths will be able to solve this in seconds. Riddles should make you have to really think and should generally be longer than this, and if they’re short, most good ones have some sort of clever ‘trick’. I recommended checking out the top rated [tag:riddle]s here to see what people are looking for

Comment: Man, the downvotes always come after the answer. I wish I could delete this, but people are very tricky!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please do not be discouraged. I have noticed that here on PSE folks seem to like challenging, original and thought provoking puzzles. It is hard to design great puzzles. Please follow @Beastly Gerbil comment. Sometimes test driving your puzzle on your friends before posting works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

> $i$ or $\sqrt{-1}$

### Explanation:

I am not real

> $i$ is called an imaginary number, and isn't part of set of real numbers aka $\mathbb{R}$

But I am part of a complicated thing.

> Complex numbers in math are written as $a+bi$

Two is negative

> By definition $ii=i^2=-1$