# Have You Heard My New Riddle?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> A stirrup I own that no stallion can wear.
>   I am not a smith though an anvil I bear.
>   My hammer? No Middle Earth dwarf gives a care.
>
> With diamonds or pearls adorned may I be.
>   The heart of my heart holds the truth secretly.
>   In truth rearranged are my letters, you see.

The answer is a single English word.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer is:

> ear

A stirrup I own that no stallion can wear.

> A stirrup is the name of a bone in the ear. Stapes.

I am not a smith though an anvil I bear.

> Anvil is another bone. Incus.

My hammer? No Middle Earth dwarf gives a care.

> The other bone. Malleus.

With diamonds or pearls adorned may I be.

> Earrings/studs etc

The heart of my heart holds the truth secretly.

> The middle (heart) of the word heart is ear.

In truth rearranged are my letters, you see.

> Are is an anagram of ear.

Comment: Oh and obviously the post title as well...

Comment: And each line (and the title) contains the word as well. Congratulations!

Comment: For the last clue, I thought it was more that the letters of "are", rearranged, make "ear".

Comment: @psmears Well spotted. I had both interpretations in mind.

Comment: @psmears that's what I put originally but someone edited it...

Comment: So they did! @bornfromanegg - could you edit the last part of the answer again, adding back in the original interpretation (that Hugh Meyers has confirmed is also correct)? Thanks :)

Comment: Done. Realised it was wrong just after I changed it, but couldn't retract it. Hoped that peer review would've stopped it!