# Hints Among Confusion

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> The Roman gods hid treasure
>   In robes of rose and green
>   A stone lay at the center
>   And gold was in between
>   Fetched by a dog named rover
>   Lee in "Show Me" was seen
>   Sir, move if you are clever
>   And tell me what I mean.

The solution is a single English word.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think this juicy rhyme concerns a

> mango

The Roman gods hid treasure

> Ro**man go**ds hides *mango*.

In robes of rose and green : A stone lay at the center : And gold was in between,

> It's peel is red and green, stone seed in the center and the golden pericarp in between.

Fetched by a dog named rover

> Hidden in 'd**og nam**ed' backwards (fetched) is *mango*.

Lee in "Show Me" was seen

> "Show Me" is the motto of Missouri state abbreviation MO → Ang (Lee) in MO gives *mango*!

Sir, move if you are clever : And tell me what I mean.

> Sir - man, move - go → mango

Title: Hints Among Confusion

> An anagram (confusion) of Among gives Mango

Comment: You got me again! Congrats! Google "Show Me state". :-)

Comment: Why *that* Lee and not [one of these?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_with_surname_Lee)

Comment: Impressive. Nice work!

Comment: @Chowzen I needed one more rhyming six syllable cryptic-style clue. Yeah, I was reaching. :-)

Comment: I guess my question was more for @Tom, how (not even using the "show me" clue at first) did he come up with *that* Lee? (BTW, I'm often *totally* guilty of "reaching.")

Comment: @Chowzen, this renowned Lee showed in the middle of the word grown from the other clues. I couldn't cut the "Show Me" clue until Hugh stated it. Succulent rhymes as always by the OP!

Comment: OIC, reverse engineered from the answer to something "Lee."

Comment: I also tried for a bit to work in "scene" instead of "seen" to clue that I was talking about a director. Couldn't make it work though.

Answer (score 4):

Could it also be a

> **Baby**? (A single English word.)

`The Roman gods hid treasure`

> The Roman God **Jupiter** was only a newborn when he was hidden by his mother **Cybele**.${}^1$ (She wanted to protect him from being swallowed by his father, **Cronos**.) 
>  <sub>${}^1$Although this is Greek Mythology, *Jupiter* was the Roman name of **Zeus** and *Cybele* was the Roman name of **Rhea**.</sub>

`In robes of rose and green`

> Jupiter was hidden in a **cave** on Mount Dicte, part of the **Lassithi Mountains** on the east of the island of Crete, Greece. Parts of the island are green, also where the [Red Cretan Tulip](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&biw=1209&bih=701&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=P2hEW__TA_eM0PEPs-ux-Ak&q=Red+Cretan+Tulip&oq=Red+Cretan+Tulip&gs_l=img.3...177898.181529.0.181789.17.9.0.0.0.0.1091.1091.7-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.img..16.0.0.0...0.6VFvDCr3tRk) grows.

`A stone lay at the center`

> A stone lay${}^2$ at the center of a **christening**. 
>  
>  Every Christian baby must be baptised; they must undergo a christening. At the center of the word "christening" is **sten** which can be derived from the word **stone** (by removing the letter that lays at the center, funnily enough). 
>   <sub>${}^2$Note that by using the word *lay* instead of *lays*, the phrase is in past tense, since a christening only happens once.</sub>

`And gold was in between`

> The baby would be baptised by a priest who would most likely be wearing robes of **gold**.

`Fetched by a dog named rover`

> A reference to the song **Hush, Little Baby** via the lyric, "*Mama's going to buy you a dog named Rover*."

`Lee in "Show Me" was seen`

> There is an actress that goes by the name of **Pui Fan Lee**. She is part of a children's television series called, "**Show Me, Show Me**". (In the children's television series, "Teletubbies", there is a character called *Po* who is also voiced by her.)

`Sir, move if you are clever`

> When babies become cleverer, they begin to crawl and **move** from one location to another.

`And tell me what I mean`

> Could you mean a **baby**?

---

**Title:**

`Hints Among Confusion`

> The riddle would be confusing if **baby** was the answer, and the acronym **HAC** also stands for [**Hospital-Acquired Condition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hospital-acquired_condition), which might relate to giving birth to a newborn in hospital since [pregnancy is a medical condition](https://www.quora.com/Is-pregnancy-considered-a-medical-condition-Why-or-why-not).

Comment: Ingenious. I believe the accepted answer is a better fit but I have to admire the work that went into this.

Comment: @HughMeyers hahah. Yes, I was running out of ideas for the "stone" part, so I came up with what I wrote. Unfortunately, your riddle does not have the `wordplay` tag, so it was unlikely of being correct, even if the official answer was not accepted. Great riddle, though! I am in the middle of writing a riddle of my own, inspired by yours, actually :)