# There is a Phobia of Climbing Me, and a Phobia of Staring at Me

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, poetry

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *I always head up or down, straight or in a spiral.*
>
> *Jacob dreamed of Heaven via me inside the Bible.*
>
> *I never head sideways, as that is a different way.*
>
> *When home alone, Kevin rode down me on a sleigh.*
>
> *Going up, I have a flight, but never have I wings.*
>
> *Climb me for a while, and it might hurt your hamstrings.*
>
> *I do have a replacement that will lift you to the higher;*
>
> *Though you can never use it if there is a fault or fire.*
>
> *My names differ, ending with a case or way or well.*
>
> *Find out what I am, and other beliefs you may dispel.*

---

This riddle might prove to be easy, 
 But to answer it, you will have to think *steady*. 
 
 There is also more than one clue in the title.

---

This is the classic style of riddle that I usually write in, and I decided to write one more like it as to celebrate my $20$th riddle created on the Puzzling Stack Exchange!

This is the $19$th riddle I have posted, but there was a riddle I wrote as an answer (over [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16106/riddles-puzzles-having-answer-hidden-in-the-question/68066#68066)). I made this riddle relatively easy so people who are not very great at riddles can also enjoy.

In celebration of my $20$th riddle here, not only will I be accepting the correct answer, but I will also be awarding the user another bonus: $100$ of my reputation!

An added $50$ of my reputation will be credited to the user who does not give the correct answer, but is very well-fitting and might pass as an alternative.

Unfortunately, I would have to wait $2$ days in order to award the bounties, but that should be enough time to answer this riddle. Hints are below.

$$\LARGE\stackrel{\bullet\,\bullet}{\smile}$$

---

**Hint:**

> *Did I forget to mention my relative, the escalator? 
>  And to be more specific, my replacement is __ ________.*

Comment: Lemme get this straight. You're not only happy to see incorrect, speculative answers, but are *rewarding them?* That's new!

Comment: @Chowzen I like to be kind, and to encourage users to contribute to this community :D

Comment: I just noticed I say the word "to" four times in that one sentence...

Comment: ***I have awarded the bounty to @QuantumTwinkie in [my following riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68469/always-never).***

Comment: @downvoter may you please explain why you downvoted? Did I do something wrong or did you not like the riddle (because this might not be your taste)? I don't care about reputation — I just want to do what is right by the community :)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie no problem. I knew I was gonna do it one day or another — you deserve it! :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you a

> Ladder/Stairs

I always head up or down, straight or in a spiral.

> That's what you use them for.

Jacob dreamed of Heaven via me inside the Bible.

> He dreamed of angles going up and down from Heaven.

I never head sideways, as that is a different way.

> That would be weird.

When home alone, Kevin rode down me on a sleigh.

> [Home Alone.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Alone)

Going up, I have a flight, but never have I wings.

> Stairs but not a flight like a plane.

Climb me for a while, and it might hurt your hamstrings.

> It could be a work out.

I do have a replacement that will lift you to the higher;

> Elevator

Though you can never use it if there is a fault or fire.

> It refers to the replacement. You cannot use an elevator during a fire.

My names differ, ending with a case or way or well.

> Stair case, stair way, stair well.

There is a Phobia of Climbing Me, and a Phobia of Staring at Me

> People may get scared and Staring-Stairs!

This riddle might prove to be easy, 
But to answer it, you will have to think steady.

> You have to be careful on the steps?

**Hints**

Did I forget to mention my relative, the escalator? 
And to be more specific, my replacement is __ ________.

> The replacement is an elevator. Which cannot be used during fire or mechanical fault.

**Congrats on your 20th post, I will enjoy seeing future posts. Have fun!**

Comment: Thank you! [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$Gur ynfg yvar bs gur evqqyr whfg svavfurf vg bss va fnlvat gung vs lbh svaq bhg jung gur nafjre vf, lbh zvtug or noyr gb qvfpneq bgure cbffvovyvgvrf (hayrff gurer vf na nygreangvir nafjre, bs pbhefr — juvpu zvtug whfg or n ynqqre!). Gur oynaxf ner fhccbfrq gb or svyyrq jvgu gjb jbeqf, bar bs gurz nyernql univat orra jevggra va lbhe nafjre...$]$ :)

Comment: Can you find out the clue(s) in the title and the little poem below the riddle?

Comment: Done @user477343

Comment: Thanks for notifying me. Sorry I could not reply earlier; I was very busy and did not have spare time, but I do now! [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$Sbe gur ynfg cneg, guvax nobhg gur fbhaqf bs gur jbeqf; sbe rknzcyr, gur jbeq "fgner" fbhaqf yvxr "fgnve" (naq gurer ner gjb fhpu cubovnf gbb, nf n znggre bs snpg). Gur fnzr vf va gur cbrz nf jryy.$]$ And last but not least, [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$Pbatenghyngvbaf ba trggvat gur pbeerpg nafjre! Rkcrpg n uhaqerq erchgngvba va n pbhcyr bs qnlf!$]$ :D

Comment: Oh, Jesus, I have been waiting to use the bounty that I forgot to award you the tick! Congratulations! $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: I must say, after I posted [my most recent anagram puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69630/i-was-inspired-to-create-a-third-and-not-final-anagram-puzzle),I did not expect that many upvotes! This means I earned more reputation than I thought I would... and since you inspired me to make anagram puzzles, I was thinking that perhaps I can give you a bounty because you deserve it. Also, you are at nearly $10$k with your reputation!  Would you like a bounty?

Comment: Oh, I don't need a bounty unless you really, really want to give me one. You deserve that reputation with your awesome puzzles, and I hope you keep posting them @user477343 :D