# Riddle on Cities. What am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

What am I?

> I was 10 times as big in Athens as in Rome
> I'm just myself in London and New York
> I traditionally count in San Francisco
> I will make you lean in Geneva

### Hint 1

> Lines C and D require computer knowledge

### Hint 2

> Line A needs historical knowledge

### Hint 3

> `lean` in line D is the verb not the adjective

### Hint 4

> `bigger` is not regarded to address size, height, or volume but amount

### Hint 5 (big hint!!!)

> The solution is imaginary

### Hint 6 (big hint!!!)

> For the solution you have to read the riddle literally

#### Edit 1

I changed 'higher' to 'bigger' in line A. This is more accurate and less misleading. 'Higher' was not wrong from my perspective, though.

#### Edit 2

I changed 'I'm' to 'I was' in line A as this is a historical fact and not relevant in the present.

#### Edit 3

I rephrased the comparison a bit in line A to avoid misinterpretations. `A is X times bigger as B` could be interpreted as `A = B + 10 * B = 11* B`, if you are really nitpicky. But here you should read `X in Athens = 10 * X in Rome` (`*` is the multiplication operator)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am

> I

I was 10 times as big in Athens as in Rome

> In Greek numerals, [iota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iota) (Greek letter I) has value 10. 
>  In Roman numerals 'I' has value 1.

I'm just myself in London and New York

> In English 'I' is the personal pronoun.

I traditionally count in San Francisco

> 'i' is commonly used for an int counter (Silicon Valley is in the southern SF Bay Area).

I will make you lean in Geneva

> `<i>` is the italic element makes *you* lean in HTML, which was invented in CERN, Geneva.
>    <sub>(Thanks to OP for above, original was 'I' standing for italic will make *Geneva (a specific typeface) lean*.)</sub>

Helpful hints:

> H1) Lines C and D require computer knowledge: int counter and typeface.
>  H2) Line A needs historical knowledge: Greek and Roman number systems.
>  H3) Lean in line D is the verb not the adjective: italic type leans.
>  H4) bigger as in amount: $10 = 10\cdot1$
>  H5) The solution is imaginary: the imaginary number $i$
>  H6) For the solution you have to read the riddle literally: What am **I**?

Comment: Trarin vf va snpg n ersrerapr gb gur PREA, jurer Gvz Orearef-Yrr vairagrq ugzy

Comment: Weil done. Did you enjoy this riddle? Did you use all the hints before you could solve it? Did I add too many hints? Our did I add them too early?

Comment: @HerrSerker - I've so far enjoyed all your riddles. I was originally on the wrong tack on line one (thinking of M). Perhaps H5 was strong. H1 and H3 were helpful! The edits are honorable, though hardly even needed. Usually on PSE hints are daily or longer. Thank you for this and would appreciate more of your creations.

Answer (score 2):

We can decode this to give

> A clock

I'm 10 times higher in Athens than in Rome

> Athens has a higher elevation than Rome

I'm just myself in London and New York

> Big Ben and the clock on Wall Street

I traditionally count in San Francisco

> The San Francisco Ferry Building Clock

I will make you lean in Geneva

> The flower clock

Comment: A good answer but is weak on Athens and Rome, both cities being at sea level. I suggest **fhaqvny** - gurer vf bar pneirq va gur pyvss bs gur Npebcbyvf, juvpu zhfg or ng n zhpu terngre ryringvba guna bar va Ebzr.

Comment: You have to take this literally

Answer (score 0):

Quick guess, not all the clues worked out yet:

Is this the

> Colosseum?

Athens -

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stegeman_Coliseum

Rome -

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colosseum

London -

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Coliseum

New York -

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Coliseum_(1928) (among other coliseum-named places in New York.)

'Frisco -

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oakland%E2%80%93Alameda_County_Coliseum

Geneva -

> https://www.sparknotes.com/lit/daisy/section5/page/2/

It could also just be

> Landmark, or something similar

Comment: Could the downvoter explain the downvote?

Comment: Have you worked out *any* of the clues?

Comment: Didn't I work out all of them? I put the links just to show that I was thinking of actual places.

Comment: Geneva is a little weak, I must admit.

Comment: I thought of this almost immediately but it didn't seem worth an answer, as there is no back-up. How does the 10x height work?

Comment: The Roman one is in ruins, and the one in Athens is a modern sports stadium. I didn't look up the exact heights, but I figured it would work.

Comment: Regarding Rome and Athens: 10 times as high is exactly. And maybe I should rephrase it to '10 times as big'. That would be more accurate on the riddle.

Comment: OK, thanks. Will try for a new solution.

Comment: I've added some hints to my question